# C++ Inheritance and how to pass and maintain subclass data through a superclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Alright, wasn't quite sure how to word the question and couldn't find any duplicates that I think really address this situation.

Essentially I have a super class that gets extra data appended to it through a subclass. The container class for this data recognizes only the super class and adjust characteristics based on an id parameter in the super class.

I've actually never had to used inheritance in c++ till recently so forgive me if this is trivial. I'm under the impression that when I go to hard copy a bunch of data using the superclass, the subclass data is loss in translation so to speak. In order to bypass this limitation I'm trying to use a typecast-ed pointer however I now get a segmentation fault when trying to free the memory even when typecasting the pointer parameter in the free() function.

Here is the sample code...

Structs

```
// Super class
struct Vertex {
    __declspec(align(4)) unsigned int vType;              // Identifies the vertex type.

    Vertex(const unsigned int _vType) : vType(_vType) { }
    Vertex(const Vertex &_rV) : vType(_rV.vType) { }      // Copy constructor
    virtual ~Vertex() { }

    unsigned int GetVType() const { return vType; }
};

// Subclass
// Id = 1
struct V_Pos : Vertex {
    __declspec(align(4)) XMFLOAT3 position;

    V_Pos(void) : Vertex(1) { }
    V_Pos(XMFLOAT3 &_rPosition) : Vertex(1), position(_rPosition) { }
    V_Pos(const V_Pos &_rV) : Vertex(_rV), position(_rV.GetPosition()) { } // Copy constructor
    ~V_Pos() { }

    XMFLOAT3 GetPosition() const { return position; }
};
```

Here is how I'm currently copying the data.

```
// pBuffer is declared as a Vertex* data type
pBuffer = new V_Pos[_bufSize];

if (_pVBuffer->GetVType() == 1)
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bufSize; ++i) {
        V_Pos *_temp = (V_Pos*)&_pVBuffer[i];
        pBuffer[i] = *_temp;
    }
```

Here is how I am currently de-allocating the data.

```
if (pBuffer != 0) {
    delete [] pBuffer;
    pBuffer = 0;
}
```

What is the correct approach for this situation?

**Edit 1 -**

Updated the above code blocks to clarify the comment discussion under knulp's answer.

Comment: Why would you want to use a subclass to update its superclass?

Comment: @JAB - My hacky attempt to update the superclass with the subclass is in order to grab the appended subclass data. The whole vertex buffer is used as a BLOB that is fed to a COM object and then forgotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start mixing low level memory allocation with malloc()/free(), and C++ objects, you will run into a lot of troubles, while making your code almost unreadable.

You should create a new object with new on a proper constructor, which automatically 1) allocates memory and 2) initializes the struct. To properly free the memory you should use delete and the destructor.

You should copy using a copy constructor and an assignment operator. If you do not define them, the default ones are automatically defined by the compiler to perform a bitwise copy.

Why are you using a type field? C++ has a very strong typing features, so it makes very little sense to bypass all C++ mechanism to define a vType. Rather, define a base class, and two or more derived classes from there, and just eliminate the vtype field.

If you use clean OO programming, you will avoid all these problems from the start.

Comment: Definitely need to work on my OO and C++ programming. However, the reason for the lower level memory allocation is I'm eventually going to allocate to specific byte alignments. As for the type field, I have to initialize D3D11 COM objects differently based on the vertex type and I don't know of any other way to tell from the base class what type of vertex it is. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @Joel - you do not need to use a custom memory allocator to handle D3D Verticies.  Stick with new/delete ... when in doubt (even when not in doubt), use the K.I.S.S. O.F.F. ("Keep It Simple and Stupid Or Face Frustration") method.

Comment: @Zac - Yeah, been thinking about the fact that it's redundant since I'm already explicitly byte aligning the member variables on top of whatever D3D/XNA optimizations have been built in. However, I do like the idea of at least having everything go through my memory class for gathering performance and profiling metrics. So the question is, overload the new operators which brings me back to square one or tie the memory allocation class in with the constructors?...

Comment: @Joel: Overloading the new operator is all but trivial. I suggest you read some good book about that. You could start from this simple tutorial: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_new.html, and then go deeper. Bruce Eckel "Thinking in C++" is freely available and has a decent explaination. However, as @Zac said, keep it simple: if you want to collect statistic, I suggest you do it in the constructors and destructors.

Comment: Ok, starting to alter the code towards the solution we discussed but I'm still baffled as to how to correctly copy the buffer. Using a dereferenced typecasted derived class pointer (that's a mouth-full) still gives me garbage data for the derived member fields once it's copied to the container class' buffer. Shouldn't C++'s polymorphism mechanisms handle this or do I need to overload the assignment operators in a specific way for both classes? Or is trying to make a class like this flexible enough to handle all the possible different vertex types a bad design decision?

Answer (score 1):

Your base class needs to have a virtual destructor. This will allow you to safely delete a derived class with a base class pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Not that! Use a copy constructor.

```
    // Super class
struct Vertex {
    __declspec(align(4)) unsigned int vType; // Identifies the vertex type.
    Vertex(const unsigned int _vType) : vType(_vType) { }

    unsigned int GetVType() const { return vType; }

    Vertex(const Vertex& v) : vType(v.vType) {}
};

// Subclass
// Id = 1
struct V_Pos : Vertex {
    __declspec(align(4)) XMFLOAT3 position;

    V_Pos(void) : Vertex(1) { }
    V_Pos(XMFLOAT3 &_rPosition) : Vertex(1), position(_rPosition) { }

    V_Pos(const V_Pos& v) : Vertex(v) { 
       position[0] = v.position[0];
       position[1] = v.position[1];
       position[2] = v.position[2];
    }
};
```

Better yet, use a vecotr instead of XMFLOAT3;

Create a copy on the heap:
    V_Pos original(...);
    V_Pos * copyPtr = new V_Pos(original);